# Get base_url using Jquery in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0. I want to get base url of laravel page using jquery.
I have tried the following function.

```
function getBaseURL () {
   return location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port && ":" + location.port) + "/";
}
```

But this gives only `http://localhost`. I need my full base url in jquery. What to do?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Do you mean you want the base url of your laravel app available anywhere your javascript?

You can include this in your template.blade.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var APP_URL = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!}
</script>
```

And than access that var anywhere in your javascript:

```
console.log(APP_URL);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var base_url = '{!! url() !!}';
</script>
```

You can call it any where in js files like
`"base_url"`

It return upto your `public` path without slash at end

`Ex: www.example.com`

If you need to add slash at end you can use this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var base_url = '{!! url().'/' !!}';
</script>
```

It return upto your `public` path with slash at end

`Ex: www.example.com/`

Answer (score -3):

The solution is easy , All you need to just use below code :-

```
var appBaseUrl = {''};
```

This variable will return something like http://yourexampledomain.com

Furthermore if you want to add your controllers and action to this url i.e. for Ajax call , then that will be simple too :-

```
var finalUrl = appBaseUrl+'/controller/action';
```

Result is :- http://yourexampledomain.com/controller/action

Now use finalUrl in your calling route for ajax calls.