# Jquery image displaying

Tags: jquery, laravel

Jquery:

```
   var res = $.parseJSON(data);

            if(res.status == true)
               {       
               //console.log(res.show.image);
                    var result = '<img src="{{asset('newuploads/+res.show.image+')}}"><br>'+
                                 'Product Name:'+res.show.product_name+'<br>'+
                                 'Price:'+res.show.price+'<br>';

                        $('#result').html(result);  
                }
            }
```

Product Name and Price are displaying but not the image. `console.log(res.show.image);` gives the proper image name but i am not being able to display the image.

In php, (laravel) this would do it :

```
<img src="{{asset("newuploads/{$show->image}")}}">
```

Comment: is the url correct?

Comment: inspect the element in browser and see what is the src value

Comment: Looks that you're missing a quote after newuploads/, try the following: var result = '<img src="{{asset('newuploads/' + res.show.image + ')}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{asset()}}` isn't meant to be used dynamically by javascript. Unless you're using `handlebars` and wrote your own helper, `asset()` just resolves as `/` in your browser, so let's just do that:

```
'<img src="/newuploads/' + res.show.image + '"/>'
```

Which will produce the same result that you're attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`asset` is a Laravel helper, see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset). Therefore, you simply **can not** use it in your JS scripts.

There are many solution for the issue, one of them at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30938647/3380506).