# Laravel - get base path in .js file not in blade template

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

If I want to get base url in blade template then I used this :

> {{ url (' / ') }}

If my script is on blade template then I used this :

```
<script>
   var base_path = {{url('/')}} // same as above.  
</script>
```

But if I add js file on my blade template then how to get **base url** on that js file?

let me show what I have tried :

first I added script file in blade template.

```
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

> test.js file

```
var base_path = "{{url('/')}}"; // not working

var base_path = "<?php echo {{url('/')}} ?>"; // not working

var base_path = "<?php {{url('/')}} ?>"; // not working

alert(base_path);
```

but this above code of peace is not working and I can't get base url.

Any idea how to deal with this small problem.

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938077/get-base-url-using-jquery-in-laravel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not access it directly using any of method

```
var base_path = "{{url('/')}}";

var base_path = "<?php echo {{url('/')}} ?>"; 

var base_path = "<?php {{url('/')}} ?>";
```

You can do following thing to acess it.

put one hidden input in footer.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{url('/')}}" id="url" name="url">
```

now you can access it in js as following

```
var base_path = $("#url").val();
```

**OR**

make one global js variable in header before initializing any js

```
const base_path = '{{ url('/') }}\/';
// ex: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

now you can use it in your js