# Laravel and AJAX get

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to use ajax method in my laravel project and I have defined a route for it:

```
Route::get('/ajax/get_discount_code','SomeController@some_method');
```

so I'm using jQuery's get function:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var url = '/ajax/get_discount_code';
    $.get( url , function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
 });
```

And I get following error:

> GET http://localhost/ajax/validate_discount_code 404 (Not Found)

The reason is, it's trying to get http://localhost/ajax/validate_discount_code rather than  http://localhost/myProject/public/ajax/validate_discount_code

In order to fix this error I can change javascript url variable and set it to:

```
var url = '/myProject/public/ajax/validate_discount_code';
```

And then 404 (Not Found) error will no longer apear and it works just fine, but I know this is not a good way to fix this error because I have hard coded 'myProject/public' into the string.
My question is, what is the best practice to fix the 404 Not Found error in this example?

Comment: you can see this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938077/get-base-url-using-jquery-in-laravel

Comment: Show how you define it in your routes.php

Comment: The [Laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute) library may also be useful in getting the URLs to routes using Javascript

Comment: @Michel Route::get('/ajax/get_discount_code','SomeController@some_method');

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel url() function to make complete url like

```
var url = "{{ url('/ajax/get_discount_code') }}";
```

Comment: I'm inside a javascript file. I cannot use laravel's template engine

Comment: You have an external js file, you are not writing js code into your blade file?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [Laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute) helper functions, you can include URLs to routes easily in Javascript:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var url = laroute.url('/ajax/get_discount_code'); // laroute.action('SomeController@some_method'); will also work
    $.get( url , function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable in the head of your main blade file where you can store the value of the baseURL like:

```
<head>
...
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var base_url = '{!! url('/') !!}';
  </script>
  //the rest of ur scripts
</head>
```

And in your script you can call the variable `base_url` and glue it with the url for the request, and this way you don't need to worry about it, plus you can change the `base_url` by just changing the value of that variable and the whole site will work just fine.

Comment: Object of class Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator could not be converted to string

Comment: @AliSeyfi add '/' inside url(), check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set-up a virtual host to resolve this.

The reason it's giving a 404 error is because localhost doesn't point to the Laravel installation so you can't reference the root URL.

You need to do something like this to set-up the vHost assuming you are using apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my-project.local
    DocumentRoot {localhost_dir}/myProject/public
    <Directory {localhost_dir}/myProject/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allowoverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/zjx_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/zjx_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You will be able to point your AJAX to the route you intend. Remember to add a line to point to locahost in your hosts file.