# API: Ajax post in Laravel - 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, api

I'm getting `403 forbidden` during ajax call.
This is happen only if the `ajax` is on `app.js`.
If I `remove` from `app.js` and put to `index.blade.php`, is working perfectly.

How can I make it working also on my `app.js`?
I've searched a lot, and found I needed to add this

> $.ajaxSetup({
> headers: {
> 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
> } });

before the ajax, but is still not working..

controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class API extends Controller
{
    public function getSomething(Request $r)
    {
        $r->validate([
            'user' => 'required'
        ]);

        $data = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();



        return $data;
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::post('getSomething', 'API@getSomething');
});
```

index.blade.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

.... some of my content ....

<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

app.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: '{{ url("api/getSomething") }}', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        user: '1',
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        _testThisAjax: true
    },
    success: function (c) {
        console.log(c);                                         
    },
    error: function(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `{{ url() }}` helper method will not work in `app.js` file so you have to set `url` in ajax

Your ajax should be like this if you put this in `app.js`

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: '/api/getSomething', 
    type: "POST",
    data: {
             user: '1',
             _testThisAjax: true
    },
    success: function (c) {
        console.log(c);                                         
    },
    error: function(e)
    {
       console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Note : use either ajax headers for csrf or in data like this:

```
 data: {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') , 'key' : 'value'}
```

FOR MORE : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf

Comment: Without the first ``/`` of the url and is work just fine. Thank you very much! Btw, is there a way to use helper method like {{ url() }} in app.js or is working only on blade.php?

Comment: its for blade but u can define it  in js also see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938077/get-base-url-using-jquery-in-laravel/30938647